# Not able to locate AWS credentials from spark application when using IMDSv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

Normally we run spark application in Ec2 instance by attaching Instance role and configured the same in spark configuration to use IAM role instead of access key and secret key.

Its working fine with IMDSV1 version but facing issue with IMDSV2 version

Error:

```
scala> spark.read.json("s3a://bucket/data*").count()
23/11/16 06:38:06 WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

I tried to update aws-java jdk and bundle to latest version,but still same issue is occuring.

I am expecting to read s3 with IMDS V2 enabled

Spark version : 3.4.1

aws java jdk jar: aws-java-sdk-1.12.599.jar

aws java sdk bundle jar: aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.599.jar

Comment: Is this native EC2 or Spark on EMR?

Comment: It's on EC2 @jarmod

Answer (score 0):

Your aws SDK version doesn't support it. Consult the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/use-a-supported-sdk-version-for-imdsv2.html) to see what 1.x version you need to switch to.

Also, don't put two versions of the aws sdk libraries on the classpath unless you like debugging classpath problems

Comment: I am using later versions of those given in the AWS documentations @stevel

Comment: sorry, missed the 1.12 prefix. yes, you are using the later version. you still need to only have one version of the jars on your CP, though that's not causing the auth problem.